# Knockout view model with mapping plugin

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I am trying to figure out how to use the Knockout mapping engine with my view model.

If I have a server side view model that looks like this:

```
public class InventoryIndexViewModel
{
    public bool IsDeleteReceiverButtonVisible { get; set; }
    public IList<Receiver> Receivers { get; set; }

    public string ReceiversAsJson
    {
        get
        {
            var jsonSerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
            };

            var receivers = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this.Receivers, jsonSerializerSettings);

            return receivers;
        }
    }

}
```

And the Receiver property is an object that looks like this:

```
public class Receiver
{
    public Cooperative Cooperative { get; set; }
}
```

And the Cooperative property is an object that looks like this:

```
public class Cooperative
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

My view looks like this:

```
@model InventoryIndexViewModel

@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    ViewBag.Title = "Inventory List";
}

@section scripts{
    <script>
        $(function() {
            var inventoryViewModel = function() {

                var self = this;

                self.isDeleteButtonVisible = function() { return @Model.IsDeleteReceiverButtonVisible.ToString().ToLower(); }();
                self.receivers = ko.observableArray(@Html.Raw(Model.ReceiversAsJson));
            };

            ko.applyBindings(new inventoryViewModel());
        });
    </script>
}

<div class="col-md-10">
    <br />
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: receivers">
            <tr>
                <td data-bind="text: serialNumber"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: cooperative.Name"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

So the question is, how to work with the complex Receiver object.  In my view code, I've tried to data-bind to cooperative.Name, but that does not work.  I am guessing that I need to use the Knockout mapping plugin, but I've tried the syntax at the Knockout page along with several different syntax variations I've found by Googling, but nothing I have tried seems to work.

On a side note, the code shown here is vastly simplified from my real code.  So, while there probably is a very easy way in this simplified code to get to the cooperative.Name through data-binding, just consider that the Receiver object is a complex object with many properties that are themselves, complex objects, so that is where the Knockout mapping engine would do the grunt work of turning everything into observables throughout the entire object hierarchy.

Or maybe it can't and I am way off base.  Thoughts?

**Edit:** Updated server side view model to correctly include the ReceiversAsJson method that I forgot to include originally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your properties are defined in the model you can serialize the model as json using mapping as follows:

**Javascript**

```
    var data = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
    var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

**View**

```
<table class="table table-striped">
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: Receivers">
            <tr>

                <td data-bind="text: Cooperative.Name"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
</table>
```

**JsFiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/wr5W7/

**Controller with example data**

```
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var model = new InventoryIndexViewModel();
            model.IsDeleteReceiverButtonVisible = false;
            model.Receivers.Add(new Receiver { Cooperative = new Cooperative { Id = 1, Name = "aName" } });

            return View(model);
        }
```

**Models**

ps I had to add an initializer to the collection i.e.

```
    public class InventoryIndexViewModel
    {
        public InventoryIndexViewModel()
        {
            Receivers = new List<Receiver>();
        }

        public bool IsDeleteReceiverButtonVisible { get; set; }
        public IList<Receiver> Receivers { get; set; }
    }

    public class Receiver
    {
        public Cooperative Cooperative { get; set; }
    }

    public class Cooperative
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

**Update**

As per comments, this is a way of using the mapping plugin with knockout computed functions:

**Javascript**

```
var aViewModel = function(data)
{
   self = this;
   ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self);

   self.firstNameAndLastName = ko.computed(function() {
        return self.FirstName() + " " + self.LastName();
    }); 

}


var data = {"IsDeleteReceiverButtonVisible":false, "FirstName": "First", "LastName": "Last", "Receivers":[{"Cooperative":{"Id":1,"Name":"aName"}}]};
        var viewModel = new aViewModel(data);
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

**Html**

```
<table class="table table-striped">
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: Receivers">
            <tr>

                <td data-bind="text: Cooperative.Name"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
<span data-bind="text:firstNameAndLastName()"></span>
```

**jsFiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/wr5W7/3/

Comment: Thanks.  I was able to get it working using your example; however, I am still wondering how you would use the mapping plugin if the view model is defined as a function (like my example) instead of an object literal.

Comment: @meyousikmann No problem, please see my update. It includes serialization from the model (with dummy data for jsFiddle) and a computed function.